# Inventory Aging Report with Adjustment Support (FIFO)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, report, sql-server-2016

Have a problem to solve in the SQL Server to generate a Inventory aging report using FIFO Based on SKU & Warehouse with adjustment support (incoming (+ve) and outgoing (-ve)). I have attached the schema here.

| SKU | TransactionType | WarehouseCode | TransactionDate | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 100 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-04-30 | 50 |
| 101 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 30 |
| 101 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-01 | 25 |
| 100 | OUT | WH2 | 2021-05-02 | 30 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-02 | 20 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-04 | 50 |
| 100 | OUT | WH2 | 2021-05-04 | 20 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-05 | 25 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-10 | 30 |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-05-11 | 30 |
| 101 | OUT | WH2 | 2021-05-12 | 20 |
| 100 | OUT | WH1 | 2021-05-15 | 30 |
| 102 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-15 | 25 |
| 102 | OUT | WH2 | 2021-05-17 | 2 |
| 102 | ADJ | WH2 | 2021-05-18 | 5 |
| 102 | ADJ | WH2 | 2021-05-18 | -1 |

Based on the above schema structure, i need to develop a inventory aging report based on first in first out (FIFO) and show the remaining qty of each SKU and Warehouse combination and make the previous incoming records remaining quantities as zero.

Expected report format Assuming the report is run on (2021-05-20)

| SKU | TransactionType | WarehouseCode | TransactionDate | Qty | Remaining | Aging |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 100 | 0 | 21 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-04-30 | 50 | 0 | 21 |
| 101 | IN | WH1 | 2021-04-30 | 30 | 30 | 21 |
| 101 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-01 | 25 | 5 | 20 |
| 100 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-10 | 30 | 30 | 11 |
| 100 | IN | WH1 | 2021-05-11 | 50 | 5 | 10 |
| 102 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-15 | 25 | 22 | 6 |
| 102 | IN | WH2 | 2021-05-18 | 5 | 5 | 3 |

Got the inventory aging report with SQL window function, need assistance adding support for adjustment.

```
WITH
  cumulative AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'IN' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY SKU, WarehouseCode
            ORDER BY TransactionDate
      )
        AS qty_in_so_far,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'OUT' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY SKU, WarehouseCode
      )
        AS qty_out_final
  FROM
    inventory
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN qty_out_final > qty_in_so_far       THEN 0
       WHEN qty_in_so_far - qty_out_final > qty THEN qty
                                                ELSE qty_in_so_far - qty_out_final END  AS qty_final,
  DATEDIFF(day, TransactionDate, '2021-05-20') + 1             AS aging
FROM
  cumulative
WHERE
  TransactionType = 'IN'
ORDER BY
  TransactionDate,
  SKU,
  WarehouseCode
```

SQL Fiddle for sample schema and query - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de36b2c43d16a0e1e69dd64561422525

Comment: Can you add detail to the question to explain what _"adding support for adjustment"_ means, mathematically and in the result?  Show the expected result and explain why that's the correct result.  Side note: the data in your fiddle doesn't seem to match the data in the question.

Comment: @JonArmstrong - I have corrected the data in fiddle. I have inventory adjustment table which accounts for human error while doing inventory stocking. It can be +ve (which can be considered as in transaction type) -ve (which can be considered as out transaction type). I need to account these values while calculating the aging report. Currently my end results depends on In inventory transaction type, when the last incoming transaction is adjustment then the sql creates discrepancy as its not accounting ADJ until the real Incoming transaction comes.

Comment: You need to update the fiddle link/url in the question.  What is the age of a -5?  You'll need to decide how to handle that.  Age is usually associated only with incoming inventory, correct?  Which incoming date do you want to adjust with any +x or -x?

Comment: @JonArmstrong Corrected the fiddle link. You are right, Age is associated only with incoming inventory, if the +ve corrected added up to previous inventory incoming date will solve my problem i think, i am not sure how to implement this

Comment: +x is the easy one, if you want to adjust the last prior incoming inventory.  It's the -x that could be a problem.  But you could subtract that from the prior "IN" as well, assuming there's enough inventory.  Otherwise, it might impact several prior "IN" transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it, for the limited data provided.

The first `CTE` terms tie the 'ADJ' rows to the corresponding prior 'IN' rows, and later simply `SUM` those group `Qty`s to derive final 'IN' rows which have the adjustments applied.

Now we use your original logic (with slight corrections) to handle the rest, no longer needing to worry about adjustments.

Limitation: If adjustment rows exist which completely remove more than the prior "IN" transaction, that will require more logic.  Unless you need that, the following should be fine.

Also note: Some of your original "Aging" results (in the question) appear wrong, and are not based on the corresponding "IN" row.

[The updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5af4e0ff6985ad0da512c7963e794ccf)

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
     SELECT i.*
          , SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU, WarehouseCode ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS grp
       FROM inventory AS i
      WHERE TransactionType IN ('IN', 'ADJ')
     )
   , cte2 AS (
     SELECT SKU, WarehouseCode, 'IN' AS TransactionType
          , MIN(TransactionDate) AS TransactionDate
          , SUM(Qty) AS Qty
       FROM cte1
      GROUP BY WarehouseCode, SKU, grp
      UNION
     SELECT SKU, WarehouseCode, TransactionType, TransactionDate, Qty
       FROM inventory
      WHERE TransactionType = 'OUT'
     )
   , cumulative AS (
     SELECT *
          , SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'OUT' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU, WarehouseCode) AS qty_out_final
          , SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'IN'  THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU, WarehouseCode ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS qty_in_so_far
       FROM cte2
     )
SELECT SKU, WarehouseCode, TransactionType, TransactionDate
     , qty_out_final, qty_in_so_far, Qty
     , CASE WHEN qty_out_final >= qty_in_so_far  THEN 0
                                                 ELSE qty_in_so_far - qty_out_final END  AS qty_final
     , DATEDIFF(day, TransactionDate, '2021-05-20') + 1             AS aging
  FROM cumulative
 WHERE TransactionType = 'IN'
 ORDER BY TransactionDate, SKU, WarehouseCode
;
```

The result:

| SKU | WarehouseCode | TransactionType | TransactionDate | qty_out_final | qty_in_so_far | Qty | qty_final | aging |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | WH1 | IN | 2021-04-30 | 125 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 21 |
| 100 | WH2 | IN | 2021-04-30 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 0 | 21 |
| 101 | WH1 | IN | 2021-04-30 | 0 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 21 |
| 101 | WH2 | IN | 2021-05-01 | 20 | 25 | 25 | 5 | 20 |
| 100 | WH2 | IN | 2021-05-10 | 50 | 80 | 30 | 30 | 11 |
| 100 | WH1 | IN | 2021-05-11 | 125 | 130 | 30 | 5 | 10 |
| 102 | WH1 | IN | 2021-05-15 | 2 | 29 | 29 | 27 | 6 |
| 100 | WH1 | IN | 2021-05-16 | 125 | 160 | 30 | 35 | 5 |